# Serving php image search results in Bootstrap modal

Tags: php, css, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to serve image results from a mysql database with php using a Bootstrap modal.

The images are served however the modal only works on the first image.

You can see a live page of it here http://www.lostedinburgh.com/home2.php (type leith to get a few results)

I understand that I have made img01 dynamic to deal with more than one image results but I am unsure how to do this.

Any help much appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$location=$row['location'];
$year=$row['year'];
$router=$row['router'];
$id=$row['id'];
$tester=$row['tester'];

echo '<div id="myModal" class="modal">';
echo '<span class="close">&times;</span>';
echo '<img class="modal-content" id="img01">';

echo '<div id="caption"></div>';
echo "</div>";

echo '<img id="myImg" src="'.$router.'" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" 
width="300" height="200">';
}
```

Here is my css:

```
#myImg {
border-radius: 5px;
cursor: pointer;
transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; /* Full width */
height: 100%; /* Full height */
overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
margin: auto;
display: block;
width: 80%;
max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
margin: auto;
display: block;
width: 80%;
max-width: 700px;
text-align: center;
color: #ccc;
padding: 10px 0;
height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {    
-webkit-animation-name: zoom;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
animation-name: zoom;
animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
from {transform:scale(0)} 
to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
position: absolute;
top: 15px;
right: 35px;
color: #f1f1f1;
font-size: 40px;
font-weight: bold;
transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
color: #bbb;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
.modal-content {
    width: 100%;
}
}
```

Here is my Javasript

```
<script>
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
modal.style.display = "block";
modalImg.src = this.src;
captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
modal.style.display = "none";
}

</script>
```

Have added classes instead of ids but the issue still exists.

Here is my html:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$location=$row['location'];
$year=$row['year'];
$router=$row['router'];
$id=$row['id'];
$tester=$row['tester'];

echo '<div class="myModal" class="modal">';
echo '<span class="close">&times;</span>';
echo '<img class="modal-content" class="img01">';

echo '<div class="caption"></div>';
echo "</div>";

echo '<img class="myImg" src="'.$router.'" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" 
width="300" height="200">';
}
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.myImg {
border-radius: 5px;
cursor: pointer;
transition: 0.3s;
}

.myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; /* Full width */
height: 100%; /* Full height */
overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
margin: auto;
display: block;
width: 80%;
max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
.caption {
margin: auto;
display: block;
width: 80%;
max-width: 700px;
text-align: center;
color: #ccc;
padding: 10px 0;
height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {    
-webkit-animation-name: zoom;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
animation-name: zoom;
animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
from {transform:scale(0)} 
to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
position: absolute;
top: 15px;
right: 35px;
color: #f1f1f1;
font-size: 40px;
font-weight: bold;
transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
color: #bbb;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
.modal-content {
width: 100%;
}
}
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
<script>
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName('myModal');
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementsByClassName("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementsByClassName("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
modal.style.display = "block";
modalImg.src = this.src;
captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
modal.style.display = "none";
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use classes instead of ids for your elements. Ids are meant for only single elements and this is why only the very first element is working.

Comment: Thanks. Should the Javascript also be changed to operate off of classes too?

Comment: @stephen251 Yes, it has too